# How this wifi http injection works?

Tags: wireless

[image]

WIRELESS HTTP TRAFFIC INJECTION [(from this tweet)](https://twitter.com/konklone/status/598696478018666496/photo/1)

How it possible? with a network middleware for adapters or what?

I read a lot about Packet Injection, i've tried libraries like JNetPCap and others.

Any programmatically solution to do it with Java or Python?

Answer (score 1):

This is more a function of injecting data into the HTTP stream than it is of specifically injecting packets into the TCP/IP stream  (although depending on how much data is being injected into HTTP, it might call for additional packets).  Whether your client is connected via Wire or Wireless is irrelevant in this particular case (although its probably fair to assume something like this would happen more often over a WiFi connection -- but it can happen to both).

Since HTTP is unencrypted, anyone between you and the end-server you're talking to can see the data being sent back and forth.  A device can be configured to intercept the incoming HTTP, add the relevant code that creates the Southwest drop down page menu, then send both the original HTTP and the new code along to the client.

A lot of load balancers these days have the ability to inject HTTP data or cookies into HTTP conversations.  A lot of Firewalls/Loadbalancers have the ability to redirect HTTP connections through a Proxy service which in turn can modify or add to the HTTP conversation.

If you're concerned about how the "new injected HTTP" works with the "original HTTP website" in so far as styling and HTML code itself.  Or even how to replicate this with a Linux box using Python/Perl/etc, then that question might be better asked on a more appropriate Stack Exchange community, since that answer wouldn't really fall within the realms of Network Engineering.